# How to initialize Full Calendar version 4 in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to use the Full Calendar version 4 so I can use mouse over events on events in background mode. For some reason I cannot initialize it in my component(set options), I mean its working when I run ng serve, but I get error on my IDE. I will post the picture error here along with my code.
Official docs you can see here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/release-notes

I tried using OptionInputs as a parameter but that didn't work

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { DataService } from './../../shared/services/data.service';
  import 'fullcalendar';
  import { Calendar } from 'fullcalendar';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
  })
 export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

 myEvents = [];

 transformDate(str: String) {
   return str.substr(0, 10);
 }
  ngOnInit() {
const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Test A',
      start: '2018-10-09T16:00:00'
    }
  ]
});

calendar.render();
```

}
}

[image]

Comment: The error is there in your screenshot. You did not put the `plugins` parameter... take a look into `OptionInputs` so see the correct options structure.

Comment: @distante   I already saw it but couldn't figure out what's wrong.  export interface OptionsInput extends OptionsInputBase {
     buttonText?: ButtonTextCompoundInput;
     views?: {
         [viewId: string]: ViewOptionsInput;
     };
     plugins: PluginDef[];
 }

Comment: Can you put together a [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) with the error?

Comment: @distante https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wpwzc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the options object in a wrong structure, it requires a plugin property

```
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Test A',
      start: '2018-10-09T16:00:00'
    }
  ],
   plugins: []
});
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dawxra?file=src/app/app.component.ts)